# How to use "grep -f file" if "file" has null-delimited items?

Tags: bash, grep, comm

I need to find null-delimited items from numerous files (`data2`, `data3`, ...) that are present in `data1`. Exact match is required.

All works well with `grep -f data1 data2 data3 ...` until the items in `data1` are also null-delimited.

1. Using only newlines - **ok**:

   ```
   $ cat data1
   1234
   abcd
   efgh
   5678
   $ cat data2
   1111
   oooo
   abcd
   5678
   $ grep -xFf data1 data2
   abcd
   5678
   ```
2. `data2` contains null-delimited items - **ok** when `-z` used:

   ```
   $ printf '1111\0oooo\0abcd\0005678' > data2
   $ grep -zxFf data1 data2 | xargs -0 printf '%s\n'
   abcd
   5678
   ```
3. Now both `data1` and `data2` contain null-delimited items - **fail**. Seems that the `-z` option does not apply to the file specified with `-f`:

   ```
   $ printf '1234\0abcd\0efgh\0005678' > data1
   $ grep -zxFf data1 data2 | xargs -0 printf '%s\n'

   $
   ```

---

The problem is that I **do need both files** to have null-delimited items.
Obvious work-around could be (for example) a good old `while` loop:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' line || [[ $line ]]; do
    if grep -zqxF "$line" data2; then
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
    fi
done < data1
```

But since I have many files with lots of items, this will be painfully slow! Is there a better approach (I do not insist on using `grep`)?

Comment: Do you need to retain ordering? Would a `comm`-style operation work as well as `grep`? (And do you *have* GNU `comm`, with `-z`?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ordering is not a problem at all.

Comment: Are you using `grep` because you really need its regular-expression-matching speed, or because you had a problem that started out simple enough to hack together a `grep`-based solution? If the latter, this is the point where you switch to a language with proper data structures, read `data` into memory, and go from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since order retention isn't important, you're trying to match exact strings, and you have GNU tools available, instead of using `fgrep` I'd suggest `comm -z`.

```
$ printf '%s\0' 1111 oooo abcd 005678 >data2
$ printf '%s\0' 1234 abcd efgh 005678 >data
$ comm -z12 <(sort -uz <data) <(sort -uz <data2) | xargs -0 printf '%s\n'
005678
abcd
```

If you generate your files sorted in the first place (and thus can leave out the `sort` operations), this will also have very good memory and performance characteristics.

Comment: That would work (+1) but since I have many files, I'd issue `sort` and `comm` many times. Is there a more efficient solution that comes to mind or do you think this will be fast enough?

Comment: @PesaThe, `comm` is very fast, and you can do the `sort`s once per file, not once per operation, so long as you retain their results.

Comment: @PesaThe, ...the other thing is -- what exactly are you trying to accomplish with your many files? If you want to look for items in both file1 and "any of file2, file3 or file4", you can do that trivially with just one `comm` invocation, comparing a sort of file1 with file2, file3 and file4 merged+sorted together. Suggesting a good solution requires knowing more about the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Oh, I could just use `comm ... <(sort -uz data2 data3 ...)`. I need a break :) Thanks, that sounds fast enough!

Comment: ...and if `data2`, `data3`, etc. are individually pre-sorted, you could use `comm ... <(sort -umz data2 data3 ...)` to join them with a merge sort, which will be even faster (and more memory-efficient).

Answer (score 2):

(Although the following may not be the best solution for this particular case, I added it anyway in case it helps some future reader with a similar problem. See below for a `gawk` solution which may be useful for this use case.)

`grep` has newline hard-wired as the pattern terminator. Even if you use `-e pattern`, newlines in the pattern string will cause grep to handle the options as specifying multiple patterns, not a single pattern containing newline characters.

However, if your NUL-separated patterns do not contain newline characters, you can use Gnu `xargs` and `sed` to construct an appropriate `grep` invocation with `-e` command-line arguments:

```
sed -z 's/^/-e/' data | xargs -0 grep -zF data2 ...
```

(This works because Gnu `grep` reshuffles command-line arguments, so it's ok to put the files to be searched before the patterns. That won't work on many other `grep` implementations.)

As far as I know, there is no workaround for patterns which may contain newline characters. `grep -E` and `grep -F` do not recgnise ascii escape sequences, and will silently create multiple patterns from a pattern which contains a newline. `grep -P` (another Gnu extension which uses PCRE regexen) will properly handle embedded newline characters or ascii escapes, but only allows a single pattern.

---

#### Full-line NUL-terminated matches without sorting

In the case that you are only interested in exact, full "line" matches (`-Fx`), you could use an Gnu Awk script rather than sorting the inputs and patterns. This could be a win for very large inputs which don't fit in memory; sorting with external temporary files can be quite expensive. The Awk solution uses a hash table, so sorting is unnecessary. (Again, this might not work on all Awks because it relies on setting `RS` to NUL.)

```
awk -v RS=`\0` 'NR==FNR{p[$0] = 1; next;} $0 in p' data data2 ...
```

Comment: Interesting, so newline is unfortunately hard-wired. My "patterns" can contain newlines, hence the null delimiter. Anyway, it was a nice read, you probably meant `< <(sed...)` though. Thanks!

Comment: @PesaThe: Oops, that was an artefact from a previous attempt. I meant to just do a simple pipe. Fixed, thanks. But if your patterns can contain newlines, you need a completely different solution; I think `grep` just cannot help you.

Comment: I am not insisting on `grep`. It just looked like a good tool for the job at the time which now I know it is not (thanks to comments/answers). Since the "patterns" are fixed (`-Fx`), the accepted solution works perfectly. Nonetheless, this answer will definitely benefit future readers! :)

Comment: I've just seen your update and I have to confess I'm a little embarrassed for trying to find some complicated `grep` solution when for fixed string I could've used very simple and intuitive `awk -RS='\0'` ...

Comment: I am also split now on whether I should change the accepted answer or not. Both answers are brilliant, your answer providing more information however...

Comment: @PesaThe: Whatever. Neither Charles nor I are hurting for rep :). The grep solution will have it's uses, but not in the case where full-line matching is actually required; I confess, I didn't see the `-x` option in your command lines until just now.

Comment: For awk, if the data contains a large number of values (lines) that don't match the 'good' list, you can reduce memory bloat (and maybe overflow) by testing `$0 in p` instead of `p[$0]/*!=0*/`

Comment: @dave: Good point. Fixed. Thanks. (If I weren't in the middle of something I'd fix `NR==FNR`, too, but it's such an idiom... Later.)